# Why $\Delta u(x)=-\int_{\mathbb R^d}\nabla _x G(x,y)\cdot \nabla f(y)dy$?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f\in \mathcal C^2_c(\mathbb R^d)$ and define $$u(x)=\int_{\mathbb R^d}G(|x-y|)f(y)dy,$$
where $$G(|x-y|)=\begin{cases}-\frac{1}{2\pi}\ln(|x-y|)&d=2\\ \frac{1}{d(d-2)|B_1|r^{d-2}}&d\geq 3\end{cases},$$
where $|B_1|$ is the volume of the unit ball.

Why $$-\Delta u(x)=-\int_{\mathbb R^d}\nabla _x G(|x-y|)\cdot \nabla f(y)dy\ \ ?$$

**Attempt**

I would say that $$\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial x_i^2}u(x)=\int_{\mathbb R^d}\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial x_i^2}(G(x,y)f(y))dy=\int_{\mathbb R^d}f(y)\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial x_i^2}G(x,y)dy,$$
And I know from my cours that $$-\Delta G(x,y)=\delta_{x=y}.$$
Therefore $$\Delta u=\int_{\mathbb R^d}f(y)\Delta G(x,y)dy=0.$$

What's wrong here ? I don't get

$$-\Delta u(x)=-\int_{\mathbb R^d}\nabla _x G(|x-y|)\cdot \nabla f(y)dy.$$

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your reasoning is that $\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial x_i^2}G(x,y)$ are not integrable near $0$. So let $f=f(u_1,...,u_d)$. Then

\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial }{\partial x_i}u(x)&=\int_{\mathbb R^d}\frac{\partial }{\partial x_i}G(|x-y|)f(y)dy\\
&=\int_{\mathbb R^d} G'(|x-y|)\frac{\partial }{\partial x_i}(|x-y|) f(y)dy\\
&=-\int_{\mathbb R^d}G'(|x-y|)\frac{\partial }{\partial y_i}(|x-y|)f(y)dy\\
&=-\int_{\mathbb R^d}G'(|y|)\frac{\partial }{\partial y_i}(|y|)f(x-y)dy\\
\end{align*}
and thus
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial x_i^2}u(x)&=-\int_{\mathbb R^d}G'(|y|)\frac{\partial }{\partial y_i}(|y|)\underbrace{\frac{\partial }{\partial x_i}f(x-y)}_{=\frac{\partial f}{\partial u_i}(x-y)}dy\\
&=\int_{\mathbb R^d}G'(x-y)\frac{\partial }{\partial x_i}(|x-y|)\frac{\partial f}{\partial u_i}(y)dy\\
&=\int_{\mathbb R^d}\frac{\partial }{\partial x_i}G(|x-y|)\frac{\partial f}{\partial u_i}(y)dy.
\end{align*}

The conclusion follow.